# morris.js and raphael.js , node_module not found

Tags: angular, webpack, raphael, package.json

I have an Angular project, and I am making use of morris.js. My package.json has the reference to both morris and raphael like this:

```
dependencies{
....
"raphael": "^2.2.7",
    "morris.js": "0.5.0",
....
}
```

I also checked in node_module folder, both dependencies exists. In mycomponent.ts , I am doing this:

```
import  'morris.js';

export class mycomponent implements OnInit {
areaChart: morris.GridChart;

.....
 this.areaChart = Morris.Area({
.....)}

}
```

I am getting an error that  "ERROR ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined"

It is getting fired from morris.js when it's doing `this.raphael = new Raphael(this.el[0]);`

How should I include Raphael in Morris to make it work?

Comment: but is your raphael.js & morris.js loaded in index.html ??? i.e if its angular cli project than have you included in your angular-cli.json ?

Comment: I have index.html, but its a angular 4 project with webpack . so they dont inlcude js files in index.html . I tried adding "import raphael" in mycomponent .ts but no help.

Comment: add raphael.js & morris.js in your index.html...!

Comment: Thats not the right way to do it..

Comment: adding in component.ts would resolve the methods, but in the final build your libraries are not included, which is why you are getting the error. its like using jQuery but you haven't included jquery.js !

Post your webpack config, then i can tell u if there is some place or not for adding external JS, otherwise include them in index.html

Comment: I have webpack.dev.js and webpack.common.js..they both are too big,.pls tell me how I can send them to you? also are you sure, they are external js.. I have imported other js in my component.ts like this :  import  'morris.js';
import 'jquery-knob';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';
import 'jqueryui';
import 'daterangepicker';
import 'jquery-slimscroll';
import 'raphael';
import 'admin-lte';
and all of them are working.. 
only  raphael is not working...the difference is rappahel is refered from inside morris.js which is another lib in node_module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153938/discussion-between-mayurb-and-parth-ghiya).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and I accomplished it by adding:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ Raphael: 'raphael' })
```

to my webpack.config.js plugins section making Raphael globally available.
I also had added:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' })
```

earlier so jQuery would work globally as well.

Comment: I have jquery in provideplugin . .. will try this for Raphael too

Comment: Oh man!! it worked...you wont belive that what all things I tried..
I tried creating alias like morris 
 alias: {
                'morris.js': 'morris.js/morris.js'
       
            }
tried changing , morris.js 
Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I have the same problem but I only use angular-cli. How can I solve this?

Comment: Thanks! For Ionic 3 projects, the file to modify is node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js